# Using BuildContext outside build function

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a function that builds a widget to be able to reuse it, and in that function I want to set the text theme. My problem is that to do that I need to access the BuildContext to do so. The only way I can think of is to  pass it as a parameter in every function call, but it feels like there must be a simpler method. Or is this the best way to do it?

Here is the current code:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:snapping_page_scroll/snapping_page_scroll.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        backgroundColor: Color(0xff121217),
         textTheme: TextTheme(
           headline: TextStyle(fontSize: 40)
         )
      ),
      home: SplashScreen(),
    ));

class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SplashScreenState createState() => _SplashScreenState();
}

class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    loadData();
  }

  //Simulates loading of data
  Future<Timer> loadData() async {
    return new Timer(Duration(seconds: 1), onDoneLoading);
  }

  onDoneLoading() async {
    Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Home()));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Color(0xff121217),
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
        child: Image.asset('assets/logo.png'),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Home extends StatelessWidget {

  Widget page(text, color, context){
    return Container(
      color: color,
      child: Align(
        alignment: Alignment(0, 0.5),
        child: Text(text, style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline,),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: SnappingPageScroll(
          children: <Widget>[
            page('Page 1', Colors.orange, context),
            page('Page 2', Colors.green, context),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use builder widget. ...
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Builder-class.html

Answer (score 3):

You have access to BuildContext inside build method.

So you can move your `place()` function inside build.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  page(text, color) {
    return Container(
      color: color,
      child: Align(
        alignment: Alignment(0, 0.5),
        child: Text(
          text,
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  return MaterialApp(
    home: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          page('Page 1', Colors.orange),
          page('Page 2', Colors.green),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Also in cases like yours a good pattern would be to create your own reusable Page widget and pass your parameters via constructor.

```
class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            _Page(text: 'Page 1', color: Colors.orange),
            _Page(text: 'Page 2', color: Colors.green),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _Page extends StatelessWidget {
  const _Page({
    Key key,
    @required this.color,
    @required this.text,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final Color color;
  final String text;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: color,
      child: Align(
        alignment: Alignment(0, 0.5),
        child: Text(
          text,
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert stateless widget to a stateful widget :)

[image]

[image]

Errors gone :)
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Define a variable from the BuildContext class at the top (for example, its name is a). Sync variable a to context under build function You can use variable a anywhere you want.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The `Theme` is usually an object that could be accessed from everywhere in your code to maintain uniform UI and consistency.

Assuming you have different themes for different parts of your app (via nested `Navigator`s, etc.), I believe that's the only time where you need the widget's `BuildContext` to find the `Theme` it's located under. In that case, I agree with Filip's answer about using a `Builder` widget.

I like to share another way to go about it is by using `GlobalKey`s, supplying it to a nested `Navigator` widget, and accessing declared key in the function. This is for those that need extra assurance that they're using the right theme. But in most cases (probably all), Flutter should be able to detect the right `Theme` which the `BuildContext` is under.